# How to rename multiple files in multiple folders with one command

Tags: windows, php, html, powershell, batch-rename

We want to rename our `*.html` files to `*.php` but (sadly enough) have not enough knowledge to do it with a cmd prompt command and/or batch file.

The problem is that each file is in separate folder –
and I am talking about 750+ different folder names.
Using wildcards for the files I know is the `*`
but using also a wildcard for folders is unknown to me.
We probably need to use the `FOR` command (in Command Prompt),
but there I am stuck.

Folder structure we use is:

```
parent-folder/child-folder/grandchild-folder/file.html
```

for example:

- `games/A/game_name/file.html`
- `games/B/game_name/file.html`
- `games/C/game_name/file.html` and so on.

The parent folder is the same for all files; the child & grandchild folders are different for most files.

After renaming these files to `*.php` I assume the following in the `.htaccess` will make a permanent redirect.

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ http://oursite.com$1.php
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`get-childItem -recurse | Where {$_.extension -eq ".html"} | rename-item -newname {  $_.name  -replace ".html",".php"  }`

This will work in PowerShell.  If you have Windows 7 or Vista, you should have it installed by default.  If you are on XP you can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7217).

Comment: Soandos, Chapeau !!!!!!!!!!!! Many thanx from this side, works like a charm.

Comment: @Charles, if this solved your problem, please click the check mark, so that everyone else that sees it will know it worked. Welcome to SuperUser.

Answer (score 3):

In command line:

```
for /f "delims=*" %a in ('dir *.html /b /s') do ren "%a" *.php
```

Note: You can replace `*.html` for other wildcard, e.g. `d:\www\*.html`.

Note 2: If using the command within a batch file, replace `%a` with `%%a` (don't ask me why)

Comment: Why do you say `"delims=*"`?  `"delims="` should be good enough (i.e., why do you specify a delimiter of **`*`**?

Answer (score 2):

Flexible Renamer is an excellent little program that will handle several different types of renaming searches/replaces.  It accepts regular expressions, and has common patterns predefined.  Additionally, it allows you to include items in subfolders, or operate on folders themselves.  It also gives you a preview of all changes that will be made.  I have used it for years, and highly recommend it.

http://download.cnet.com/Flexible-Renamer/3000-2248_4-28799.html

Answer (score 2):

Using forfiles, we can write a script, to rename files recursively in all subfolders.

```
forfiles /S /M *.html /C "cmd /c rename @file @fname.php"
```

Source: [Batch script for renaming files in bulk](http://www.windows-commandline.com/2009/01/rename-file-from-command-line.html)

Answer (score 0):

TotalCommander: *Search - Send to Panel - Multi-Rename Tool*